# Access android view api of a nativescript layout

Tags: nativescript

Android has a clipChildren method for allowing the contents of a view to overflow the view's containing area. I'd like to set this to false since it seems to be set to true by default. I'm trying to access the native android view and set this using the following in nativescript:

```
var view = topmost().currentPage.content.getViewById('viewname');
view.android.setClipChildren(false);
```

But this doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your case and to make it work I have just changed the way I am calling my current page

```js
var page = args.object;
var grid = page.getViewById('viewname');

grid.android.setClipChildren(false);

console.log('grid clipChildren: ' + grid.android.getClipChildren()); // returns false
```

Comment: Thanks. This will help get me in the right direction. I'm using angular2 with nativescipt though and I haven't figured out how to attach a method to when an element loads (to then get the args parameter), but once I figure that out, this will help.